# How to set my widgets' size and padding dynamically to fit window in Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am new to Tkinter and still learning. My desktop resolution is 1366x768 and I am developing for an environment which is 2048x768. Right now I am setting the window resolution by detecting it like this -

```
w = main_container.winfo_screenwidth()
h = main_container.winfo_screenheight()
main_container.geometry(str(w) + "x" + str(h))
```

Now I have several screens and I cannot use grid on each and every screen. Like I have a Login Screen in which I have a Frame like this-

```
self.frame_background = tk.Frame(self.frame_parent, bg='#ffffff')
self.frame_background.pack(fill='both', expand=True, padx=100,
                               pady=100)
```

This is just an example of one widget. Since values for padx and pady are fixed with 100, if I am running my application on a 640x480 resolution device, the layout gets too stretched and almost nothing is visible inside this frame.
How can I set these padx and pady and other width and height values dynamically according to the screen size and resolutions?

Comment: Something like `padx=0.05*w` and `pady=0.1*h`?

Comment: Why are you setting padx and pady to such huge numbers? Are you guessing that that's enough to make the widget fit the screen? Have you tried using other pack options such as `fill="both"`?

Comment: @acw1668 can you explain how did you come up with these values of 0.05 and 0.1?

Comment: It is just an example, you need to adjust the values to suit your case.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're asking. Please [edit] the code to include a [mcve]. It's hard to tell what you mean by "scale" - do you want the fonts to grow and shrink? A canvas to grow or shrink? Button borders to get wider and narrower? Something else?

Comment: Well, all I want is buttons, frames, labels, entries to grow or shrink according to the screen resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now I have several screens and I cannot use grid on each and every screen.

Why can't you? There's nothing preventing you from using `grid` on every screen. Though, it's actually quite common to mix and match `pack` and `grid` in different frames, and arguably a best practice.

> Like I have a Login Screen in which I have a Label like this...

The code following that statement doesn't have a `Label`, so it's hard to know what you are trying to do.

> if I am running my application on a 640x480...

First you say you have a desktop resolution of 1366x768, then say you are targeting 2048x768, and are now asking about 640x480. That's a pretty wide range of values. If you have to support something as low as 640x480 you definitely should not be hard-coding padding to such huge values. Typically padding is never more than one or two. Tkinter apps can be made to accommodate that wide range of screen sizes, but that relies on *not* hard-coding the size of widgets and padding as much as possible.

> How can I set these padx and pady and other width and height values dynamically according to the screen size and resolutions?

Generally speaking, you shouldn't do that. The general rule of thumb with tkinter is that you make the widgets the smallest size they need to be and let the geometry managers worry about stretching or shrinking them to fit the available space. There are a few exceptions to that rule, but in general, that rule works quite well.

Unfortunately, geometry management questions are hard to answer without knowing more about what you're trying to do. For example, we need to know why you think you need padding of 100 pixels. That seems highly unusual. Plus, we need to know what else is in your frame, what your frame is in, and so on.

My advice is to remove the padding, or set them to very small values. Then, make sure you use all of the geometry manager options that are available to you, such as `fill` and `expand` with `pack`, and `sticky` and others for `grid`.

Comment: Actually I am making a game that will be running on wide varieties of terminals for different clients, so these terminals will have different sizes for different clients. I want to make something dynamic, so that the widgets get scaled automatically, and as far as not using grid is concerned, the person working before me on this project has made all the previous games using pack and not grid and I dont want to redo all the work again and change it to grid. Is there any workaround where I can support different screen resolutions so the widgets get scaled automatically?

Comment: @AmanGrover: Saying you don't _want_ to use grid is different from saying you _can't_ use grid. Regardless, both `grid` and `pack` can be used to make responsive UIs.  You're going to have to be more specific in your question. It's not at all clear what you mean by "scale", and why you can't just use the options of `grid` or `pack` to make your UI responsive.